# Max number of Rows printed on Console

Tags: r, printing, console, max

how to limit the max number of rows print on Console in R? For example, I only want to see 4 rows printed.

Comment: how to change the setting of max number of rows print? so i dont have to call head() again each time i want to print a matrix

Comment: `options("max.print")` changes the option for printing to the console.  But how it prints depends on its width. See `help(options)`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just use the `head` function.

`head(Dataframe, n = 4)`